# How does EventEmitter handle multiple eventListeners that use the same callback function?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, reference, eventemitter

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

const myCallback: () => void = () => {
   console.log('handling update event');
};

const ee: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

ee.on('update', myCallback);
```

Given an hypothetical application's architecture grants the chance to multiple users to listen to the `update` event maybe through an express' server `get route`, each new listener that gets created as the result of the `EventEmitter.on(...)` function call is factually the same as every other one since the context is identical?

Putting it in other words, after multiple clients have created their own listener, does:

```
ee.removeListener('update', myCallback);
```

remove all `update` events since they share the same context? Or does `removeListener` check for the callback's *reference* which I would imagine being different for each listener created?

Comment: It’s unclear what exactly is the meaning of “context” here. It’s not used as tech term. Any way, it doesn’t matter where a listener was added and how a function was called. removeListener removes only the very same function (=== equal) from the list of listeners. Check the docs, they are specific on that.

Comment: @EstusFlask thank you. I used the word "context" with the intention to elaborate on binding a different `this` context to the callback function that is used to specifically identify a eventListener, as you pointed out, and how binding context changes the comparison behaviour. I'll update the title.

Comment: It's not show now you bind `this`, myCallback is an arrow (also there are syntax issues). But this is likely unimportant as any way that you can use to bind `this` results in another function. add/removeListener or any other API that works the same way doesn't care if it's bound function or not. It checks if it's equal, and `fn.bind(whatever) !== fn.bind(whatever)`.

Comment: @EstusFlask I have edited the title of question exactly because `this` binding is not shown, to clarify what my doubt is. I had no clue `fn.bind(t) !== fn.bind(t)`, thank you.